# How to run on_reaction_add commands

Tags: python, discord.py

So I'm trying to create a discord.py bot, I'm using on_reaction_add to run the bot but it isn't working. When I run the script nothing happens, no error messages no nothing and I'm confused about what to do.

This is the whole code:

```
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import utils

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!"')
@bot.command(name = '!"Help Ban', help = 'Bans a user')
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(
        type=discord.ActivityType.watching,
        name='for !"help'))
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(bot))

@bot.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    message = reaction.message
    if message.message_id == **CHANNEL NUMBER**:
        member = utils.get(message.guild.members, id=message.user_id)
        channel = bot.get_channel(**CHANNEL NUMBER**)
        message.channel.send(f'@here, {member} wants to do parole')

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if '!"Ban' or '!"ban' in message.content:
        run = True
        if discord.utils.get(message.author.roles, name="Lord Jeebus") or discord.utils.get(message.author.roles, name="Supreme Lord Jeebus"):
            messageTrue = message.content
            messageTrue = messageTrue.split(' ')
            Player = messageTrue[1]
            Original = Player
            Player = Player.replace('<', '')
            Player = Player.replace('>', '')
            Player = Player.replace(',', '')
            userID = Player.replace('@', '')
            userID = userID.replace('!', '')
            member = await message.guild.fetch_member(userID)
            banned_role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name="Death Row")
            try:
                reason = messageTrue[2]
                await member.guild.ban(member, reason=reason)
                await member.edit(roles=[])
                await member.add_roles(banned_role)
                await message.channel.send(f'{Original} now has 2 minutes before they are banned')
                timer = 120
                while timer != 0:
                    time.sleep(1)
                    timer -= 1
                await message.channel.send(f'{Original} has been banned')
                await member.ban(reason=reason)
            except:
                await message.channel.send(f'Could not ban user as no reason was given')

    await bot.process_commands(message)

bot.run('TOKEN')
```

And this is the bit I'm stuck on:

```
@bot.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    message = reaction.message
    if message.message_id == **CHANNEL NUMBER**:
        member = utils.get(message.guild.members, id=message.user_id)
        channel = bot.get_channel(**CHANNEL NUMBER**)
        message.channel.send(f'@here, {member} wants to do parole')
```

This code should be saying `@here, Member wants to do parole` it is supposed to do that in a private channel that is has access to but nothing is coming up, even in the command console.

Comment: Your code is very jumbled. Why do you use `@bot.event` once and `@commands.Cog.listener()` in the next step? This makes no sense at all, because you obviously don't have a `Cog` here. Also, I am pretty sure it is `reaction.message.id` and not `[...].message_id`

Comment: @Dominik, I'm new to this reaction thing, I've done a lot of googling and trying to find out the answer before I asked it here but I cant find anything on it.

Comment: Just to understand the meaning: You are comparing the `reaction.message.id` to the `channel id`, what sense do you think that makes? Is it your goal that everyone in the channel can react and if one reacts, the bot sends a message into your `channel`? Also, please refrain from leaving changes to your post uncommented in the comments. Reply to the comments, that way people can help you.

Comment: yes, that is what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code contains many errors and some wrong thinking. If you are new to Python/Reactions, then I would recommend tutorials or the [Docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

Many things in your code are also redundant.

**First)** `message.message_id` is wrong. You always query the ID of a channel, server etc. with `.id` and not with `_id`

**Second)** You don't need to query `member` at all. You have `user` as an argument and don't use it, that makes no sense. Accordingly, this line is also omitted.

**Third)** If you want to give the bot an instruction to send a message to the corresponding channel, you always have to do this with an `await`, this is completely missing in your code. You define `channel` but tell it to send the message in `message.channel`, so the bot has TWO specifications

**The new code:**

```py
@bot.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    if reaction.message.channel.id == PutYourChannelIDHere: # Check if the reaction is in the correct channel
        channel = bot.get_channel(PutYourChannelIDHere) # Define your channel
        await channel.send(f'@here, {user} wants to do parole') # Send it to the CHANNEL
```

**The output:**

[image: Output of the bot]

Comment: So, ive tried it and yet it still gives me the same problem, no error and also no response, is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @Hunter Maybe try to activate and import Intents, otherwise something else in your code may be wrong. Using `print` statements can help.